# Finding f(x) when given the tangent line?

Tags: calculus

Find $f(x)$ if $f(0) = 3$ and the tangent line at $(x, f(x))$ has slope $7x$.

Would I integrate $7x$ then plug in $(0,3)$ into the point slope equation?

Comment: Integrate $7x$ and use $f(0)=3$ to find the constant "$C$" of integration.  Your suggestion will give the same result but in a more tedious way.

Comment: You integrate then find the constant of integration is 3 because f(0)=3

Comment: An fyi for the general case: Using $C=f(0)=3$ does not always work.  It is valid in this case because we're integrating a polynomial.  But, that method fails when you are not integrating a polynomial; for example, if the slope were $e^x$.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange! I have edited your question a bit using TeX. E.g., the equation f(0) = 3 becomes $f(0) = 3$ if one encloses it in \$ signs.  As to your question: Recall that for a curve with equation $y = f(x)$, the slope at the point $(x,f(x))$ is $f'(x)$. So your assumption tells you something about $f'(x)$. Use that to get as much about $f(x)$ as possible and use the condition $f(0) = 3$ to get the remaining information. But don't assume that there will be a point slope form!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you know that $f'(x) = 7x$, so $f(x) = \frac{7x^2}{2}+C$, where $C$ is a constant. Because of the other condition, $C=3$, so that your function is $f(x) = \frac{7x^2}{2}+3$.